# All natural transformations from $\operatorname{id}_{\textsf{Grp}}$ to itself

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism, natural-transformations

I am trying to find all natural transformations from the functor $\operatorname{id}_{\textsf{Grp}}$ to itself.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G @>{\phi}>> H \newline
@V{\alpha_G}VV @VV{\alpha_H}V \newline
G @>{\phi}>> H.
\end{CD}

That is, I am looking for a family ${(\alpha_G:G \to G)}_{G \in \textsf{Grp}_0}$ of morphisms such that the diagram above commutes. I figured out that defining for each $G$, $\alpha_G(x) = x$ or $\alpha_G(x) = 0$ would work respectively, and I felt like that would be all the options, but then I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872440/natural-transformations-id-ab-rightarrow-id-ab?rq=1) and now I am not sure about my assertion anymore.

I tried to come up with more examples for defining $\alpha$, but without any success.
For any two groups $G$ and $H$, I would want $\alpha_G$ and $\alpha_H$ to 'behave similarly', e.g. in the case of abelian groups $\alpha_G(x) = -x$ would work (since inverses are preserved by group homomorphisms).

However, $\alpha_G(x) = -x$ would only be an automorphism if $G$ is abelian, so I considered defining $\alpha_G$ such that it would send $x$ to its inverse if $G$ is abelian and to itself otherwise - just to come up with some example. Obviously this did not work, since for some abelian group $G$ and some non-abelian group $H$, we would have $\phi(x) = \alpha_H(\phi(x) = \phi(\alpha_G(x)) = \phi(-x)$.

Maybe my first intuition was right anyway. To prove that there are no other natural transformations from $\operatorname{id}_{\textsf{Grp}}$ to itself other than the identity transformation and the one sending everything to zero I would need to show that:
If for *any* group $G$ there exists an automorphism $\alpha_G$ different to the trivial automorphism and the identity, then there exists a homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to some group $H$ such that we cannot find an automorphism $\alpha_H:H \to H$ such that $\phi \circ \alpha_G \neq \alpha_H \circ \phi$. But how would I go about this?

Comment: Try using the same trick as in the post you linked: it is still true that $\alpha_{\mathbb{Z}}$ determines $\alpha$, but this time you'll see that not all possible $\alpha_{\mathbb{Z}}$ are allowed.

Comment: Hm, ok ... I'm actually also not sure why that is true in the abelian case. I was trying to use the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups first, but acutally we are not only dealing with _finite_ abelian groups, so I guess I am slightly on the wrong track with that approach. I guess I should think of it more abstractly somehow.

Comment: What is the set of morphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to H$ for an arbitrary group $H$?

Comment: I think the set of morphisms would be of the same size as $H$ (i.e. in bijection to it), right? Ok - I think I see now how it works in the abelian case, thanks. I'm still unsure about how to restrict $\alpha_\mathbb{Z}$ in the general case though.

Comment: You should be able to show that $\alpha_H(x)=x^n$ for all $H$ and $x\in H$, where $n=\alpha_{\mathbb{Z}}(1)$. Then you can see which $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ actually do yield a well-defined natural transformation.

Comment: Thank you, these were very good hints, but I am still a bit confused. Wouldn't we have $\phi(\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(x)) = \phi(\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)^x) = \phi(\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1))^x = \phi(1)^{\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1) x} = \phi(1)^{x \alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)} = {(\phi(1)^{x})}^{\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)} = {(\phi(x))}^{\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)} = \alpha_H(\phi(x))$ for all choices of $H$ and $x \in H$? So then all $n = \alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)$ would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us write $n=\alpha_{\mathbb{Z}}(1)\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now let $H$ be any group, and $x\in H$. Then there is a unique group morphism $\phi_x: \mathbb{Z}\to H$ such that $\phi_x(1)=x$. Apply the commutative diagram to show that $\alpha_H(x)=x^n$.

This means that $\alpha$ depends only on $n$. Now what are the values of $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\mapsto x^n$ is a well-defined group morphism for *all* groups?

Comment: Oh, I see that I missed that fact that $x \mapsto x^n$ must be a homomorphism in my comment above. I recall from my algebra course that groups for which such automorphisms exist are called $n$-abelian and I just looked up that a group $G$ is $n$-abelian iff $|G|$ is coprime to $n(n-1)$. I suppose that would mean then that in fact only $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ work, for otherwise we can take $H = \mathbb{Z}_n$, for which $\alpha_H$ as defined above is not an automorphism. Thank you!

Comment: You do not want alpha to be an automorphism: only an endomorphism.

Comment: True. I was mixing up the terminology - but actually groups for which such _endomorphisms_ exist are called $n$-abelian, so my conclusion should still be correct, right?